# Is there any cap on number of tuples generated out of one tuple from a Apache Storm Bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

One of our Bolt breaks a large tuple message down into its children and then emits these children as tuples. There can be 10000 children some times.

This bombardment of tuples, choke down our topology.

Is there any cap/ceiling value on the number of tuples generated out of one tuple in a Bolt?

We need to send these children further down the topology so that state of these children can be updated according to state of parent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cap where Storm's algorithm for tracking tuples breaks down, but that cap is at the point where you start to see common collisions between 64-bit random values. So no, there effectively isn't a cap.

What you might run into is that it takes too long to process all the child tuples, so the whole tuple tree hits the tuple timeout. Either you can increase the timeout, or you can detour over e.g. Kafka so the entire processing doesn't have to happen within a single tuple tree's processing time.

A setup like

Topology A: source -> splitter -> Kafka

Topology B: Kafka -> processing

lets you process each child individually instead of having to handle all 10k tuples within the message timeout of the parent.

Please elaborate if you meant something else by your topology being choked.

Comment: You understood right. What is disadvantage of having this setup: source -> Bolt1 -> Kafka -> Bolt2 under one topology?

Comment: Do you mean source -> bolt1 -> kafka -> kafka spout -> bolt2, or how are you reading from kafka into bolt2? So essentially just one topology with two spouts, one reading from source and one reading from Kafka?

Comment: yes. even kafka (source) -> spout -> Bolt1 (transformation) -> kafka -> Spout -> Bolt2 (further processing). If we keep everything in single topology, is there any harm in that?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It should be fine. The only disadvantage is that you can't deploy the two parts separately, but you probably don't need to do that anyway.